# Visual Studio Code - Live Server with a Github repo

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, server

I'm working with my GitHub repo using the Github Repositories extension, but the Live Server extensions don't seem to be compatible with it. Is there a way to launch a live server from a GitHub repository?

Comment: What happens when you try to use Live Server?

Comment: On [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) the button to go live doesn't show up at all, because that extension requires you to open a folder to go live from. On [Five Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yandeu.five-server) it does allow me to click the button, but when it opens in my browser it shows an error page.

Comment: Do you mean that you only have the files in git, not checked out?

Comment: I have the files saved within a GitHub repository, and I am accessing them in VSCode with [GitHub Repositories](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.remotehub). I want a live server to be created from my instance of VSCode, that allows me to quickly make edits without pushing to github and having to wait for the website to update.

Comment: Why don't you clone/checkout the files so that you have them locally, play around doing changes and test using Live Server, and the commit your changes and push them to GitHub?

Comment: I have been doing that, but it’d be much more convenient to be able to interact with my repo without creating a local copy.